# Указатель на массив символов char *tmp;  cin>>tmp;

Tags: массивы, указатели, c++

**Обьясните пожалуйста почему работает этот код:**

```
cout << "Test: ";
char *tmp;
cin>>tmp;
cout << "Test: " << tmp << std::endl;
```

Comment: что конкретно у вас вызывает удивление?

Answer (score 4):

tmp хранит мусорный указатель и куда то указывает. Вам просто повезло, что та память, куда он указывает, доступна на запись. Но никто не знает, что там хранилось до этого. Возможно там  было что то важное.

Инициализируйте свои переменные. Всегда.

Comment: Я думал что при таких операциях компилятор ошибку выдаст. Так как это нарушает целостность каких то данных.

Comment: компилятор не обязан это сделать. Он может только предупредить. Но можно (а для начинающих часто даже нужно) добавить параметр компиляции `-Wall`. В этом случае компилятор подскажет (тестил на gcc и clang). А если добавить ещё `-Werror`... то будет нужное поведение.

Один раз, когда я получил проект, в котором была куча ошибок во время работы, я просто перекомпилил с `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. Прошелся по всем ошибкам и поисправлял почти все. После этого заработало значительно лучше.

Comment: Нашёл ответ в книге Прата (771 стр.).

Указатель не выделяет память под хранение входных строк. (Программа скомпилируется нормально, но скорее всего, завершится аварийно, когда cin попытается сохранить введённые данные в неподходящем месте. )

Comment: @folax: ваша книга немного обманывает. Использование неинициализированной переменной есть undefined behaviour, программа имеет право делать **вообще что угодно**. (Особенно при жёсткой оптимизации.)